# SVG elements piled up when drawn separately

Tags: svg, position, glyph

I have an `.svg` file with two `glyphs`.  When I draw them separately using their respective `d` attributes, they appear one on top of the other.

I am not able to determine how to use the rest of the information contained in the `.svg` file to print them in their correct relative positions.

**Details** (some most likely irrelevant).

1. Compile `$-1$` in `LATEX` (with standalone package)
2. Convert the `.dvi` file to an `.svg` file using `dvisvgm` (see below).
3. Draw the two 'glyphs' using their "d" attributes (after suitable conversion to the appropriate format for `aggdraw.Symbol`). (Another surprise: the glyphs appear flipped upside down...)

```
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 1.9.2 -->
<svg height='7.61312pt' version='1.1' viewBox='-72 -71.9747 13.3666 7.61312' width='13.3666pt' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
<defs>
<font horiz-adv-x='0' id='cmsy10'>
<font-face ascent='775' descent='-960' font-family='cmsy10' units-per-em='1000'/>
<glyph d='M659 230C676 230 694 230 694 250S676 270 659 270H118C101 270 83 270 83 250S101 230 118 230H659Z' glyph-name='minus' horiz-adv-x='777' unicode='㐀' vert-adv-y='777'/>
</font>
<font horiz-adv-x='0' id='cmr10'>
<font-face ascent='750' descent='-250' font-family='cmr10' units-per-em='1000'/>
<glyph d='M294 640C294 664 294 666 271 666C209 602 121 602 89 602V571C109 571 168 571 220 597V79C220 43 217 31 127 31H95V0C130 3 217 3 257 3S384 3 419 0V31H387C297 31 294 42 294 79V640Z' glyph-name='one' horiz-adv-x='500' unicode='1' vert-adv-y='500'/>
</font>
</defs>
<style type='text/css'><![CDATA[
text.f0 {font-family:cmsy10;font-size:10.5px}
text.f1 {font-family:cmr10;font-size:10.5px}
]]>
</style>
<g id='page1'>
<text class='f0' x='-72' y='-65.2334'>㐀</text>
<text class='f1' x='-63.8638' y='-65.2334'>1</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Per the [SVG Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/fonts.html#SVGFontsOverview) Unlike standard graphics in SVG, where the initial coordinate system has the y-axis pointing downward (see The initial coordinate system), the design grid for SVG fonts, along with the initial coordinate system for the glyphs, has the y-axis pointing upward for consistency with accepted industry practice for many popular font formats.

Comment: You can call dvisvgm with option `--no-fonts` that condenses all the font data to path elements representing the glyphs. These are usually much easier to postprocess.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks!  That explains!

Comment: @Martin I will follow your advice.  I don't need to work with fonts (in some other respect it was a bit easier for me to start playing with fonts than with path strings).  Still, I would like to understand how to position the glyphs correctly...